# How to replace or remove text from URL within a loaded document?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I remove text from a static URL inside a loaded document. For example.. I have..

```
<a href="mylink.html#something">My Link</a>
```

How can I remove **#something** from that **href** using jQuery? So it would then display as..

```
<a href="mylink.html">My Link</a>
```

Also if it helps.. I can't remove anything containing **#** because what I am doing is adding another hashtag in place of it. The problem is I am getting a result like the following...

```
<a href="mylink.html#something#somethingelse>My Link</a>
```

**EDIT**

My jQuery...

```
$('ul li a').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href") + "#something");
});
```

What I would like to do..

```
$('ul li a').each(function () {
   //remove #something from href if it is already there and replace with #somethingelse
   $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href") + "#something");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VisioN .. Thanks for your help. But this is what I was looking for.

```
var changeHref = $('ul li a').attr("href").replace(/#something/, "#somethingelse");
$('ul li a').attr("href", changeHref);
```

Comment: That's no need in regexp here. Use simpler: `.replace("#something", "#somethingelse")`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove hash from the anchor `href` attribute you can use this:

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, value) {
    return value.substring(0, value.indexOf("#"));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XUTqX/

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this in with my current code.. I will do an edit to show my jQuery...